# How to call a method from a forward declared class?

Tags: c++

```
class A;

class B
{
  int something(A &objct)
  {
    return objct.ans(1);
  }
}

class A
{
 int ans(int num)
 {
  return num;
 }
}
```

My original code is too long so this is an example of code that makes the same error with mine.
In this case, it shows 'invalid use of incomplete type' error. Probably that is because the method is declared later than class B. I wonder how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to declare the class method, first:

```
class A;

class B
{
  int something(A &objct);
}
```

And only after both `A` and `B` are defined, you can define `B`'s class method:

```
int B::something(A &objct)
{
  return objct.ans(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define the function later as well:

```
class A;  // Declare A

class B {
  int something(A &objct); // Declare Function
}

class A {  // Define A
 int ans(int num) {
  return num;
 }
};

int B::somethingA( ...) { // Define Function
    ...
```

Comment: How do we call it in a word?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you elaborate?